# Excel: convert from date to time range

Tags: excel, time, data-conversion

I have a column of date in this format:

```
2019-04-17 16:26:17
2019-04-17 16:26:22
2019-04-17 16:26:27
2019-04-17 16:26:32
2019-04-17 16:26:37
2019-04-17 16:26:42
2019-04-17 16:26:47
2019-04-17 16:26:52
2019-04-17 16:26:57
```

If, for example, the first date is the time `t = 0` how can I calculate the time span, in seconds, that elapses at the following dates/times? That data table was automatically generated in .xls file by software during the lab experience. This is an example of the result I would like to achieve

```
0
5
10
15
20
25
...
125
```

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set your data appropriately this should work:

[image]

In cell `B1` this formula:

```
=A1-$A$1
```

Assumptions:

- Column A formatted: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`
- Column B formatted: `[s]`

Drag down your formula...